# Enable CPU Monitoring Metrics in Azure

Tags: azure, monitoring

I have three Azure services - a standard .NET application deployed to one, a WCF service to another and the third is a WindowsService.

I have enabled verbose logging on all instance (but not changed any code to support logging). All three are connected to the same Azure storage account.

1. The .NET instance is now logging CPU and memory metrics fine.
2. The WCF instance is logging memory usage but not CPU.
3. Likewise the WindowsService is logging memory usage but not CPU.

I can't understand what the difference is - (2) and (3) simply show a flatlined CPU which I know is not the case (as I can remote to the box and see CPU usage manually).

Does anyone have any ideas on what the difference is?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you configure (all the three) Diagnostics for the services? and what do you use to monitor the values? Are you talking about the graphics that shows up in the `Dashboard` in Management Portal?

Comment: Yes, sorry I am simply referring to the graphics display in the Management Portal. I have not done any configuration aside from within the management portal - i.e. selecting the metrics I want in the "Monitoring" screen and selecting "Verbose" in the Configuration screen. All accounts are also linked to my storage account too.

Comment: there the CPU is averaged on every 5 minutes. don't expect to see line like the one you see when you RDP and you have a refresh interval of 1 second. Have you waited enough time and loaded your services enough to produce any CPU usage? And when you say `I know is not case`, what is the case? What CPU usage do you see when you RDP to the instance?

Comment: After RDP'ing, I can see the CPU spiking at 100% every so often, however, admittedly much of the time it is very low indeed. One of the things that confused me, but could again be explained by the 5-minute averaging, is that the CPU Max and CPU Min in Azure's table in the monitoring screen were both 0%. I believe there is a problem though in that I ran a performance test recently which knocked over the WindowsService - still the Azure graph showed 0%. Perhaps a tool such as http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-diagnostics-manager/introduction would help me?

Comment: I think this is a bug of some kind in the Azure monitoring. I am following up with this thread now: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/67d8d3d6-2112-4c80-83d7-d1b896457e07/cant-see-cpu-usage-for-cloud-service-in-azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to watch the "Monitoring, Management & DevOps in Windows Azure"
https://channel9.msdn.com/(A(-6U-pJH5zAEkAAAANmJlY2IzMGItZWMzNS00MWU0LWIxNmEtNTNkMDMxZDBmYjgyubegdSHFWEu7r941495i4kaqXyQ1))/Events/Build/2013/3-558